# Bootstrapping a compiler: why?

Tags: compiler-construction, theory, bootstrapping

I understand *how* a language can bootstrap itself, but I haven't been able to find much reference on *why* you should consider bootstrapping.

The intuitive answer is that the language you're writing offers utilities that are not found in the "base" language of the compiler, *and* the language's features are relatively well-suited for a compiler.

For instance, it would make sense to bootstrap a C++ compiler -- it could potentially be much easier to maintain the compiler when OOP is properly used, as opposed to using plain C.

On the other hand, MATLAB certainly makes matrix math a lot easier than plain C, but I can't see any apparent benefits from writing a MATLAB compiler/interpreter in MATLAB -- it seems like it would become *less* maintainable.  A similar view could be applied to the R programming language.  Or a pretty extreme example would be bootstrapping [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/), which is written in Haskell -- definitely a massive *super*set of Whitespace.

Is the only reason for bootstrapping to take advantage of the new language's features?  I know there's also the "because we can" reason, but that's not what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Whitespace is pretty maintainable actually. You just need to use syntax highlighting. :)

Answer (score 39):

There's a principle called "eating your own dogfood". By using a tool, you demonstrate the usefulness of the tool.

It is often asked, "if the compiler for language X isn't written in language X, why should I risk using it?"

This of course only applies to languages suitable for the domain of compiler writing.

Comment: I think just about every *good* language I've used has been designed and written in conjunction with a program that uses it.  Sometimes it's its own compiler, sometimes not, but a compiler is a great first case.  In addition to being immediately useful, a compiler is a pretty sophisticated program (or can be), and if you can write your own compiler, it's probably going to eat simpler problems for breakfast!

Answer (score 18):

There are two main advantages to bootstrapped language implementations: first, as you suggest, to take advantages of the high-level features of said language in the implementation. However, a less-obvious but no less important advantage is that it lets you customize and extend the language without dropping into a lower layer written in C (or Java, or whatever sits below the new language runtime).

Metaprogramming may not be useful for most day-to-day tasks, but there are times where it can save you a lot of duplicated or boilerplate code. Being able to hook into the compiler and core runtime for a language at a high level can make advanced metaprogramming tasks much easier.

Answer (score 13):

Ken Thompson's [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing)#Reflections_on_Trusting_Trust) explains one of the best reasons for bootstrapping. Essentially, your compiler learn new things for every version of the compiler in the bootstrapping chain that you will never have to teach it again.

In the case he mentions, The first compiler (C1) you write has to be explicitly told how to handle backslash escape. However, the second compiler (C2) is compiled using C1, so backslash escape handling is natively handled.

The cornerstone of his talk is the possibility that you could teach a compiler to add a backdoor to programs, and that future compilers compiled with the compromised compiler would also be given this ability and that *it would never appear in the source!*

Essentially, your program can learn new features at every compilation cycle that ***do not have to be reimplemented or recompiled in later compilation cycles*** because you compiler knows all about them already.

Take a minute to realise the ramifications.

**[edit]:** This is pretty terrible way to build a compiler, but the cool factor is through the roof. I wonder if it could be manageable with the right framework?

Answer (score 10):

It can be considered the bar that separates "toy" languages from "real" languages. If the language isn't rich enough to implement itself, it's still a toy. But this is probably an attitude from a largely bygone era, given the number of popular languages today that are implemented in C.

Comment: I disagree with the categorization of "toy" vs "real".  Languages serve a purpose.  Some are general purpose languages like C, VB, etc which can be used to invent themselves.  Others, like MATLAB, are specialized for the purpose of solving specific classes of problems.  This doesn't make them "toy" languages, just specialized.

Comment: A language don't even need to be Turing Complete to be bootstrapped with itself so the bar is very low.

Answer (score 8):

One advantage would be that developers working on the compiler would only need to know the language being compiled. Otherwise developers would need to know the language being compiled as well as the language the compiler is written in.

Comment: That's not a very big deal though I don't think. Typically, a compiler writer should know many, many languages (or really, any computer scientist).

Comment: You might be surprised.  I speak several languages, but when I had to try maintaining a system that was documented in the two I know best (English and German), I found it to be at least 10 times as difficult as maintaining one entirely in English.  Little impedance mismatches really add up.

Answer (score 3):

Low-level languages are often bootstrapped because in order to put code on the new system, you need a low-level compiler there. Get a C compiler over and now you have tons of code available to use. Having a bootstrapped compiler makes this easier, you only require the presence of your own code in order to compile and improve your own code.

There are other ways to accomplish this, like making a cross-compiler, on most systems you never need to be able to compile static languages on the device itself in ordinary use (in fact, systems like Windows ship with no compiler).

Another reason compilers often bootstrap is so that they don't have to worry about bugs in the compiler they are compiled with. Ensure your compiler can be compiled with itself and you limit the combinations of bugs that might otherwise appear if you compile with another compiler.

I think bootstrapping high-level languages is mostly done to show off one's hairy-chested programming skills.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrapping has also another advantage: If your language is nice, you might save time by writing your compiler in <insert language here> than in let's say C. For instance, the C# compiler was written in C++, but now they are rewriting it in C#, which allows them (among other things) to use the threading framework from the CLR instead of rolling their own in C++ (and to follow the lead of the Mono guys as well, marketing wise, Mono was in a better position by being able to say our C# compiler is actually written in C#).

Answer (score 3):

Compilers solve a wide variety of non-trivial problems including string manipulation, handling large data structures, and interfacing with the operating system.  If your language is intended to handle those things, then writing your compiler in your language demonstrates those capabilities.  Additionally, it creates an exponential effect because as your language includes more features, you have more features you can use in your compiler.  If you implement any unique features that would make compiler-writing easier, you have those new tools available to implement even more features.

However, if your language is not intended to handle the same problems as compilation, then bootstrapping will only tempt you to clutter your language with features which are related to compilation but not to your target problem.  Self-compilation with Matlab or SQL would be ridiculous; Matlab has no reason to include strong string manipulation functions and SQL has no reason to support code generation.  The resulting language would be unnecessary and cluttered.

It's also worth noting that interpreted languages are a slightly different problem and should be treated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

As a concrete example, in [version 1.5](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5) (released august 2015), Go switched into being a fully bootstrapped language<sup>[[1]](https://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#)[[2]](http://golang.org/s/go13compiler)</sup>. They listed the following reasons:

- Go is easier to write (correctly) than C.
- Go is easier to debug than C (even absent a debugger).
- Go is the only language you'd need to know; encourages contributions.
- Go has better modularity, tooling, testing, profiling, ...
- Go makes parallel execution trivial.

Of these, the only one that would hold for all languages is that you only need to know one language to contribute to the compiler. The other arguments can be summarized as "Our new language is better than the old one". Which should probably be true, why else would you write a new language?

Answer (score 2):

You don't bootstrap a compiler for DSL. You don't write an SQL query compiler in SQL. MATLAB might look like a general purpose language, but actually it isn't -- it is a language designed for numerical calculations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons you might want to do it (in theory):

1. Your compiler generates more
   optimized code than other compilers
   on the bootstrap platform.
2. Your compiler generates more correct
   code than the other compilers on the
   bootstrap platform.
3. You're convinced that one of the above is
   true even though it's not.
4. There isn't a compiler available on
   your platform (this was GCC's
   original logic, because many
   platforms didn't have a C compiler
   back in the day).
5. You want to prove that your compiler
   can handle it (this is, after all, actually a pretty good test of a compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrapping is expected from a *general purpose programming language* .